# Loading data bigger than the memory size in h2o

Tags: java, r, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, h2o

I am experimenting with loading data bigger than the memory size in h2o.

H2o [blog](http://h2o.ai/blog/2014/03/h2o-architecture/) mentions: `A note on Bigger Data and GC: We do a user-mode swap-to-disk when the Java heap gets too full, i.e., you’re using more Big Data than physical DRAM. We won’t die with a GC death-spiral, but we will degrade to out-of-core speeds. We’ll go as fast as the disk will allow. I’ve personally tested loading a 12Gb dataset into a 2Gb (32bit) JVM; it took about 5 minutes to load the data, and another 5 minutes to run a Logistic Regression.`

Here is the `R` code to connect to `h2o 3.6.0.8`:

```
h2o.init(max_mem_size = '60m') # alloting 60mb for h2o, R is running on 8GB RAM machine
```

gives

```
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

.Successfully connected to http://127.0.0.1:54321/ 

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         2 seconds 561 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.6.0.8 
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_RILITS-HWLTP_tkn816 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   0.06 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    4 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  2 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 

Note:  As started, H2O is limited to the CRAN default of 2 CPUs.
       Shut down and restart H2O as shown below to use all your CPUs.
           > h2o.shutdown()
           > h2o.init(nthreads = -1)

IP Address: 127.0.0.1 
Port      : 54321 
Session ID: _sid_b2e0af0f0c62cd64a8fcdee65b244d75 
Key Count : 3
```

I tried to load a 169 MB csv into h2o.

```
dat.hex <- h2o.importFile('dat.csv')
```

which threw an error,

```
Error in .h2o.__checkConnectionHealth() : 
  H2O connection has been severed. Cannot connect to instance at http://127.0.0.1:54321/
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 54321: Connection refused
```

which is indicative of out of memory [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882686/why-connection-is-terminating/33029404).

> Question: If H2o promises loading a data set larger than its memory capacity(swap to disk mechanism as the blog quote above says), is this the correct way to load the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap-to-disk was disabled by default awhile ago, because performance was so bad.  The bleeding-edge (not latest stable) has a flag to enable it: "--cleaner" (for "memory cleaner").
Note that your cluster has an EXTREMELY tiny memory:
`H2O cluster total memory:   0.06 GB`
That's 60MB!  Barely enough to start a JVM with, much less run H2O.  I would be surprised if H2O could come up properly there at all, never mind the swap-to-disk.  Swapping is limited to swapping the data alone.  If you're trying to do a swap-test, up your JVM to 1 or 2 Gigs ram, and then load datasets that sum more than that.

Cliff

Comment: Thanks cliff. I was trying to test the `swap-to-disk` feature purposefully restricting the RAM usage of H2O. I will do that bleeding edge release and more RAM.

Comment: @Cliff, has any one you know of, tried using swap-to-disk on a much faster (order of magnitude faster) PCIE3-NMVe-M.2-connected solid state disk device like a Samsung 960 Pro?  My luck has been that I keep finding datasets that are just a wee bit too big for my system.... I might build a data mining rig specifically for use with H2O and one of those, and as much RAM as I can afford too.